# how can i use '__set__'

Tags: python

```
class A(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):#why i can't find argument 'key',where is 'key'
        #print ower.instance
        print instance,owner
    def __set__(self,instance,value):
        instance=value

class X(object):
    a = A()

xx=X()
xx.a='aaa'
print xx.a#None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hettinger's [HowTo Guide for Descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) covers this well. Quoting from it:

> Descriptor Protocol
>
> `descr.__get__(self, obj, type=None) --> value`
>
> `descr.__set__(self, obj, value) --> None`
>
> `descr.__delete__(self, obj) --> None`
>
> That is all there is to it.

So, you can name the arguments however you wish, but there's typically no argument named `key` to `__get__` (no idea why you're trying to find it).

Again an example from that URL:

class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

```
def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
    self.val = initval
    self.name = name

def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    print 'Retrieving', self.name
    return self.val

def __set__(self, obj, val):
    print 'Updating' , self.name
    self.val = val
```

So normally you set `self.something` in `__init__` (and/or `__set__` if you define it), and return something based on `self.something` in `__get__`. Of course this example just `print`s the "something" on getting and setting, normally you'd do something more substantial;-).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to be using __getattribute__? It has a parameter that is commonly called key; although it can be any name at all. And the definition that you have for __set__ looks like it should be for __setattribute__

Answer (score 1):

I think you could read about descriptors:

http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm

Or maybe what you want is to customize attribute access:

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access

Maybe this pointers can help you, or maybe you can be more specific?